# In US English, what is the meaning of the phrase "linger on the stoop"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this phrase in a sentence that goes like this:

> He handed me the books and the pizza and we talked for a while. He lingered on the stoop for a moment.

Can anyone please explain what is the meaning of this expression? I couldn't find a proper explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not an idiom.  The dictionary should be able to tell you the meaning of the words:

> **[stoop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stoop)** (n): *a structure that is part of the front of a house consisting of a few steps leading up from ground level, often with a raised, flat area near the door*
>
> [**linger**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/linger) (v): *to take longer than usual to leave or disappear:*

So if someone "lingers on the stoop", it means they spent a longer time than usual or expected, on the front part of a house near the door.

Comment: Thank you! I knew the individual meaning of "linger" and I am more familiar with "stoop" as a verb. I have never seen them used together like this.